# problems with bundle install on openshift: nokogiri not building

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openshift, nokogiri, ruby-2.0

I'm using OpenShift and trying to upload a simple application when I got this error:

```
Using kaminari (0.16.3)
Using mysql2 (0.3.16)
Using nested_form (0.3.2)
Installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- mini_portile (LoadError)
from     
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from extconf.rb:395:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/openshift/XXYY/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/openshift/XXYY/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The gems that I added were:

```
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 4.0.0.rc'
gem 'seed_dump'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
```

I'm using Ruby 2.0 and rails 4.1.4 (from the quick start recipe). I tried to build the gem by hand by logging into the server, but I get the same error.

/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- mini_portile (LoadError)
        from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in`require'
        from extconf.rb:395:in `'

Is there any workaround (or solution) that I can make to avoid the building problem with nokogiri?

Added the Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.4)
      actionpack (= 4.1.4)
      actionview (= 4.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.4)
      actionview (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.4)
      activemodel (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.4)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    builder (3.2.2)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.1)
    devise (3.5.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.1)
    font-awesome-rails (4.3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    foundation-rails (5.5.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.2.0, < 3.4)
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.1.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    minitest (5.8.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    mysql2 (0.3.16)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paper_trail (4.0.0.rc2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.0)
      request_store (~> 1.1)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-pjax (0.8.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.4)
      actionpack (= 4.1.4)
      actionview (= 4.1.4)
      activemodel (= 4.1.4)
      activerecord (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails_admin (0.6.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7)
      rails (~> 4.0)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    railties (4.1.4)
      actionpack (= 4.1.4)
      activesupport (= 4.1.4)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (0.9.6)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    request_store (1.2.0)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.3.14)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    seed_dump (3.2.2)
      activerecord (~> 4)
      activesupport (~> 4)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (3.3.3)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.2.2)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  cancan
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  devise
  foundation-rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  minitest
  mysql2
  paper_trail (~> 4.0.0.rc)
  rails (= 4.1.4)
  rails_admin
  rake (~> 0.9.6)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  seed_dump
  spring
  sqlite3
  thor
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Added the Gemfile.lock

Comment: From the manual install attempt, it looks like the 'mini_portile' gem needs to be installed. Try gem install mini_portile; if that works then try running bundle install again. Side-note: I highly recommend using rvm to manage not only ruby versions, but gems via rvm's gemset functionality. (https://rvm.io/)

Comment: Make sure nokogiri dependencies are all installed as addressed here http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#red_hat___centos (sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel zlib-devel)